# Finding equivalent capacitance

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

How do you find capacitance when the switch is closed, and how do you find it when it's not? Our professor just skipped this. You would help a lot of people!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOaYC8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please draw the circuit in CircuitLab (edit your question and hit Ctrl-M). I'm having a hard time making out some of those capacitance values.

Comment: I can't make it out either. Just label them C1, C2, no need for values

Comment: Then draw it yourself.

Comment: I meant that you consider them as C1 C2.. :)

Comment: And which ones do you want to call C1, C2, etc.? You should draw the circuit yourself so you can label the capacitors. I told you how to draw it in CircuitLab.

Comment: How do I draw diagonal lines

Comment: Making excuses and saying your sorry doesn't fix the crappy schematic. There are many ways to draw a decent schematic, including the built-in schematic editor. -1 for the sloppy mess.  There is no excuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how the topology morphs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the switch open, you have the three rightmost capacitors in series, with the resulting capacitance in parallel with the middle cpacitor.

With the switch closed, the two capacitors above and to the right of the switch are shorted, so can be ignored.

Comment: So if it's a open switch I can completely ignore the diagonal line?
And why are these two cut off? Current would be going in circles or what? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if the switch is open it may as well not be there.  When the switch is closed, it is the same as a solid wire, or short circuit, between the corners of the square.