# Finding equivalent capacitance part II

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Here's [part I](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136119/finding-equivalent-capacitance/136125?noredirect=1#comment274784_136125)!

They helped me a lot. But this problem is harder so if you can tell me where, if, I went wrong.[image]

When first switch is closed, the other one's opened. And in reverse.

Here's solution [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkt5n.jpg).

Here's solution [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISOkR.jpg).

P.S. Series come before parallel, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the solutions is correct, I think that the arrangement misled you.

I've rearranged the capacitors. Does it help in calculating the total capacitance?

The trick is, figure out how the current flows from A to B, where it branches and where it merges again.

## Case 1

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvh9Hv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

## Case 2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flHmut.png)</sup>

Comment: Ah, I now understand how rearranging works. Thanks